# Can't connect to wireless network in openSUSE

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, opensuse

I had Windows XP. Recently I installed openSUSE Linux on my other drive. I had access to the internet through a wireless connection in Windows XP. For openSUSE I wanted to configure my wireless network too.

I went to YaST, and scanned the network. It finds my ESSID successfully. In Windows XP, I would enter my password, but there are no options like passphrase/ASCII/decimal for encryption. Also, the device type is grayed out.

If I'm wrong and the password of my network card shouldn't be entered there, then what should I do?

When I type `ifconfig` in terminal, I get `eth0` and `eth1`.

[image]
[image]

the output for iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      unassociated  ESSID:"Nikparsa"  Nickname:"nikparsa"
          Mode:Managed  Channel=0  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   Sensitivity=8/0
          Retry limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:3335-3421-3638-4343-0000-0000-00   Security mode:restricted
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eth1      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: What version of openSUSE is it?

Comment: I was in a bad mistake my version is 11.1 and I can access internet via lan successfully but not with wireless

Comment: 11.1 is not supported either. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opensuse#Version_history
I had problems with wireless in 11.2, upgrading to 12.1 resolved them.

Comment: what a locky person i am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem myself:D
I went to **knetworkmanager** and it had problem running because in `Yast->networkdevices->networksettings` I should choose `user controlled with knetworkmanager`
then I went to shell and typed knetworkmanager then I runned it and I choose my wireless device and then I entered the shared key in next steps
I enjoy my linux now so much even with lower version choroba:)
CHEERS

Comment: Lucky you. But you might still have problems on some networks (e.g. some formats of certificates were not supported) without upgrading.

Comment: well I am in home:) and wireless and lan is enough now by the way thank you so much:) I will upgrade it as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your system. Versions 10.* were released in 2005 - 2007 and are not supported since 2009.

Comment: I know but I don't have time you mean it is not possible?i don't think so